# Definition of a smooth variety for arbitrary field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is a smooth variety? I can't find a definition of this online, except when the constant field is algebraically closed. Not smooth scheme (I have not even learnt scheme yet), but smooth variety. And the constant field can be anything, not necessarily algebraically closed, or even perfect. In particular, there might not be any rational points, which make the Jacobian definition seemed off.

Comment: Intuitively a variety is smooth if it is smooth at every point. Over a field which is not necessarily algebraically closed there's a question about what you mean by "point." One thing you might mean is point over the algebraic closure, in which case you can just apply the Jacobian criterion. There is also a scheme-theoretic definition which does not involve looking at points over the algebraic closure.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: so there is no standard definition of smooth variety then?

Comment: No, I'm saying there are two definitions (and they probably agree but this isn't obvious and I haven't checked it).

Comment: Here is the standard definition. For any variety over any field $k$, the sheaf of 1-forms, $\Omega^1_{X/k}$ makes sense and it is a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules. The dimension of the variety also makes sense. Then smoothness (over $k$) is equivalent to demanding that this sheaf is locally free of rank, the dimension.  If you haven't done sheaves, etc., the question is local and assume that $X$ is affine. Then the requirement is the module $\Omega^1$ as above is a projective module of rank $=\dim X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a variety over a field $k$. Let $k\to \overline{k}$ be some algebraic closure of $k$.

Then $X$ is smooth over $k$ if and only if the following holds:

The variety $X_{\overline{k}}$ obtained by considering $X$ as a variety over $\overline{k}$ is smooth (in the usual sense).

So, in fact, knowing what it means to be smooth over algebraically closed fields is all you need to know in order to define what it means for a variety to be smooth.

(Note that this is a well-defined notion in the sense that smoothness of $X$ is independent of the choice of $k\to \overline{k}$.)